# Spring Boot - How to send POST form-data MultipartFile to a Flask server

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, flask

I want to use restTemplate to send 3 images wrapped by MultipartFile to a Flask server.

Here's my Flash server code:

```
@app.route('/id-card-analyze', methods=['POST'])
def analyze():
    print(request.files)
    img_data = request.files
    img1 = open_image(BytesIO((img_data['file1'].read())))
    img2 = open_image(BytesIO((img_data['file2'].read())))
    img3 = open_image(BytesIO((img_data['file3'].read())))
    images = [img1, img2, img3]
    prediction = [str(learn.predict(img)[0]) for img in images]
    return jsonify(type=prediction)
```

I use Postman to test and it works:
[Postman form-data images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS5SQ.png)

Here's my Java code:

```
public ResultDTO validateIdCard(MultipartFile file1, MultipartFile file2, MultipartFile file3) throws IOException {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    try {
        parts.add("file1", new ByteArrayResource(file1.getBytes()));
        parts.add("file2", new ByteArrayResource(file2.getBytes()));
        parts.add("file3", new ByteArrayResource(file3.getBytes()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parts, headers);

    String url = "http://localhost:5000/id-card-analyze";

    // I've tried both requests but they're all 400
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    JSONObject json = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity,JSONObject.class).getBody();
    return new ResultDTO("wer");
}

2019-09-18 13:06:39.871  WARN 17109 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 BAD REQUEST
```

I've tried both requests but they're all 400
What is the correct way to achieve this functionality in a RestTemplate?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the exact same problem.